# How Do I Make Android WebView Load Page Modal Elements?

Tags: java, android, webview, popup, hybrid

I'm trying to make a really simple app for a friend to display his bar's ordering website in an app for when they reopen with the social distancing measures in place. The web app already exists, so this is really a simple matter of displaying the content in a WebView.

I've got the page loading, the content is visible, the styling is done - The only problem is that it doesn't seem to be loading all the elements. There's a line of filters at the top which just display as 3 dots (i.e. loading), and when I click any of the items on the menu, nothing happens. There should be a window pops up asking for a table number etc... If I open this in the Chrome browser on my phone, rather than a webview in the app it works perfectly so I know it isn't the website.

I've done the following;

```
setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

I've also turned off safe browsing in the manifest in case that was blocking anything. I have also given the app permissions to use the internet. I can't figure this one out at all and nothing online seems to be helping!

Admittedly I'm a tester (automated, but still), so coding isn't my best suit. I may be missing something really simple here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Scratch that. For anyone who's interested, I needed to add this line;

```
setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

For such a simple thing it proved impossible to find info on, I just enabled everything until something worked! So hopefully you don't have to do the same if you're looking at this.